# Qual a diferença entre os diretórios assets, res e raw no Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os diretórios `/assets` e `/res` presentes no android, sei que o layout e várias imagens ficam no diretório `/res` e são acessadas de diferentes modos.

Existe também o diretório `/raw` que está dentro do `/res`, sei que ele pode conter arquivos e que podem ser acessados como por exemplo `.getIdentifier("arquivo","raw", getPackageName());` onde o `arquivo` é equivalente a `res/raw/arquivo.json`, ou seja, o `raw` pode conter os mesmos arquivos que o `assets`?

Qual a real diferença entre o `raw`, o `assets` e o `res` no Android, e como eu poderia usar cada um deles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes de responder a diferença, uma breve explicação sobre os *resources*:

Alguns itens devem ser externalizados (imagens, strings) para mantê-los independentes e para eles poderem suportar configurações específicas (linguagem do device, tamanho da tela, orientação, etc.).  A pasta **`res`**, usa várias subpastas que juntam os *resources* por tipo e configuração.

Mark Vasconcelos, em seu artigo sobre [Android – Estrutura e organização da aplicação](https://markytechs.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/android-estrutura-e-organizacao-da-aplicacao/), fez um "resumo" sobre a estruturação da aplicação:

> As pastas criadas automaticamente no projeto que serão usadas pela
>   aplicação são:
>
> - **`src`**: É onde fica o código fonte da nossa aplicação.
> - **`res`**: Pasta de *resources* da aplicação, aqui ficarão arquivos de layout, imagens, XML de configuração, XML com strings
>     internacionalizáveis, raw files, sons, etc..
>
> As pastas criados por *default* para *resources* são:
>
> - **`res/drawable-<screen cfg>`**: Deve se colocar as imagens, a divisão entre hdpi (High dpi), mdpi (Medium dpi), ldpi (Low dpi)  é
>     para guardar as imagens em resoluções diferentes.
> - **`res/layout`**: Fica os arquivos XMLs que representam o layout das nossas `Activities`.
> - **`res/values`**: XMLs que guardam strings que podem ser usadas na aplicação.
>
> Por *default*, um arquivo `strings.xml` é criado nessa pasta, os
>   valores são guardados através de tags com a seguinte estrutura
>   `<string name="nomeString">Valor String</string>`
>
> Na pasta **`res`** é possível adicionar mais subpastas para
>   representar mais *resources* para aplicação ou alternativas para os
>   *resources*, como por exemplo uma pasta `xml` para guardar informações de configurações.
>
> - **`gen`**: pasta de fonte gerado
>
> Essa pasta também guarda código fontes, mas ela só fica com uma única
>   classe gerada automaticamente pelo plugin do eclipse chamada "R" no
>   mesmo pacote que informamos em "package name" quando criamos nosso
>   projeto. Essa classe `R` contém ids para todos os itens que temos na
>   pasta **`res`**, e é através desses ids que podemos usar todos os
>   *resources* facilmente na nossa aplicação.
>
> - **`assets`**: Arquivos raw - A diferença de colocar arquivos `raw` aqui do que em algo como **`res/raw`** é que *resources* são
>     acessíveis por id através da classe `R`, arquivos nessa pasta podem
>     ser abertos por stream dentro da aplicação como um byte array.
>
> Ainda é possível adicionar mais pastas no projeto, para criar
>   aplicações nativas é criado uma pasta chamada **jni** que guarda os
>   códigos nativos e `AndroidMakeFiles` que o Android NDK (Native
>   Development Kit) usa para criar a shared lib para aplicação, como
>   Android é uma distro unix, a shared lib é um arquivo com extenção
>   **.so**, os arquivos gerados pelo NDK ainda vai para outra pasta chamada libs, essa pasta contém as shared libs que podem ser usadas na
>   aplicação em `Runtime`, que pode ser carregada com um
>   `System.loadLibrary(“nomeLib”)`.

Vale a pena ler essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583782/5327226) do stackoverflow em inglês.

**Qual a real diferença entre o `raw`, o `assets` e o `res` no Android, e como eu poderia usar cada um deles?**

- **`res`**: Você deve sempre usar os arquivos e pastas de *resource* para armazenar valores da sua aplicação, além das imagens, é claro. Dessa forma você consegue manter e atualizar seu código muito mais facilmente, além de poder definir alternativas para cada um deles, de acordo com situações específicas, como diferentes idiomas, tamanhos e orientações de tela. A pasta **`res/`** é a pasta do seu projeto que guarda todos os *resources* da sua aplicação
- **`raw`**: Salvar arquivos ativos em vez de  salvar no `assets/directory`. A diferença está na maneira que você vai acessá-los. Esses arquivos são processados ​​por aapt e deve ser referenciado a partir da aplicação que utiliza um identificador de recurso na classe `R`. Por exemplo, este é um bom lugar para a mídia, como MP3 ou Ogg.
- **`assets`**: É mais como um sistema de arquivos e oferece mais liberdade para colocar qualquer arquivo. Em seguida, você pode acessar cada um dos arquivos nesse sistema. Este diretório é bom para coisas como detalhes do jogo, dicionários, ... etc.

Referência:

- [Projects Overview](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html)
- [Projeto Android](http://tableless.com.br/a-pasta-res-e-os-resources-em-um-projeto-android/)
- [Fornecimento de recursos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

- **assets/**

Você pode usar esta pasta para armazenar qualquer arquivo. Os arquivos que você salva aqui são compilados no *.apk* e o nome do arquivo original é preservado. Você pode navegar neste diretório da mesma forma que um sistema de arquivos típico usando URIs e ler arquivos como um fluxo de bytes usando um [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). Vale lembrar que a classe [R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) não gera **ID**s para os arquivos colocados nessa pasta, então ela é menos compatível com algumas classes e métodos do Android. Além disso, é muito mais lento acessar um arquivo armazenado nesta pasta, uma vez que você precisará obter um identificador para ele com base em um String.

*Exemplo de uso:* Armazenamento de texturas e dados de jogos, e bancos de dados *sqlite* .

- **res/**

Contém todos os recursos que não são códigos (*e.g.* .java, .kt), como layouts XML, strings de UI e imagens de bitmap. Esta pasta é dividida em subdiretórios. Basicamente, essa pasta serve apenas como um agrupador de outras pastas com outros recursos, como as pastas **animator**, **color**, **drawable**, etc. Os arquivos contidos nas subpastas desta pasta são processados ​​pelo **aapt** (**A**ndroid **A**sset **P**ackaging **T**ool), portanto os arquivos destas subpstas devem ser referenciados no aplicativo usando um resource ID da classe R.

- **raw/**

Assim como a pasta **assets/**, esta pasta serve para armazenar qualquer arquivo. A diferença é que, como essa pasta é uma subpasta da pasta **res/**, os arquivos contidos nela são processados ​​pelo **aapt** (**A**ndroid **A**sset **P**ackaging **T**ool), portanto eles devem ser referenciados no aplicativo usando um resource ID da classe R.

*Exemplo de uso:* Armazenar mídias, como arquivos MP3 ou Ogg.